# converting mouse genes to human genes

Tags: r, seurat, single-cell, conversion

I'm trying to convert mouse genes from PTX data to human genes in order to do a comparison with patient data to see what genes are being conserved. I'm using this file for the orthologs.
**http://www.informatics.jax.org/downloads/reports/HOM_MouseHumanSequence.rpt**

I read the table with:

```
gene_conversion <- read.table("HOM_MouseHumanSequence.rpt.txt", sep="\t", header=T, fill=T)
```

I have subsetted the mouse genes from the PTX seurat object to only include the mouse genes with:

```
mouse_only <- subset(scData, features = mouse_1)
head(rownames(mouse_only))
[1] "Xkr4"    "Gm37180" "Gm37363" "Gm19938" "Sox17"   "Gm6085"
```

Now I'm not sure how to convert the mouse genes in my mouse-only seurat object to match the human genes in the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just checking / confirming... shouldn't that be a double equals in the subset command? are you using `features == mouse_1`?

Comment: No, just a single equals. When I run the command with double I get an error.
`subset(scData, features == mouse_1)
Error in FetchData(object = object, vars = unique(x = expr.char[vars.use]),  : 
  None of the requested variables were found:`

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks. This seems to be an undocumented / new feature of subset that I haven't encountered before.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mice genes are usually the same as the human ones, but lower case with only the first character as upper (`Sox17` -> `SOX17`).
`toupper(rownames(mouse_only))` will do the trick.

Unfortunately, there are exceptions, and it is always better to relay on information from databases. The function bellow takes a vector of human genes, and uses `biomaRt` to return the corresponding genes in mouse.

```
# from Human to Mouse
convertHumanGeneList <- function(x){

   library("biomaRt")
   human <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
   mouse <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")

   genesV2 <- getLDS(attributes = c("hgnc_symbol"), filters = "hgnc_symbol", 
                 values = x , mart = human, attributesL = c("mgi_symbol"), martL = mouse, uniqueRows=T)

   humanx <- unique(genesV2[, 2])

   return(humanx)
}
```

You simply need to invert the 2 and you should be able to convert your vector `rownames(mouse_only)`

#---- Update using SOX17 as example
[image]

Comment: That didn't work. genesV2 is empty.

Comment: Works for me. I added a figure in my answer to show you the output I get

Comment: Figured out the issue, I didn't assign `x` a value. Now that I have the human genes, how can I do a correlation between the mouse genes from the PTX data vs the genes from patient data?

Comment: That's probably a topic for another question :D. You should accept the answer (if you managed to convert the genes name), and open a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
#create the function to convert mouse to human genes
homologs = read.csv("http://www.informatics.jax.org/downloads/reports/HOM_MouseHumanSequence.rpt",sep="\t")
ms2hs <- function(gene_list){
  output = c()
  for(gene in gene_list){
    class_key = (homologs %>% filter(Symbol == gene & Common.Organism.Name=="mouse, laboratory"))[['DB.Class.Key']]
    if(!identical(class_key, integer(0)) ){
      human_genes = (homologs %>% filter(DB.Class.Key == class_key & Common.Organism.Name=="human"))[,"Symbol"]
      for(human_gene in human_genes){
        output = append(output,human_gene)
      }
    }
  }
  return (output)
}

#apply the function
msgenes=c("Zfp192", "Ifitm2", "Mettl8", "Kcnh2", "Npdc1", "Pitpnc1", "Ooep", "Mettl8")
ms2hs(msgenes)
```